# layout clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I would like to make my layout clickable I set android: clickable = "true" ... but in the java code should call a new intent ... how can I do?
**XMLcode here**

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:clickable="true">
            <TextView android:textColor="#424243" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="Visibilità Personalizzata" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_gravity="bottom"></TextView>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/freccetta" android:src="@drawable/freccetta" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_height="30dip" android:layout_width="30dip" android:layout_gravity="bottom"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:textColor="#424243" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="Imposta per quanto tempo vuoi vedere gli amici che si sono disconnessi" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:clickable="true"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a OnClickListener on it :

```
//onCreate
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
layout.setOnClickListener(yourOnClickListener);
```

Should be working ;)